# PHP UTF8 decode not working for out returned from python

Tags: php, python, utf-8

i get a reply from python server basically what i am doing is sending an article and the python code is sending me important tags in the article. the reply i get is like this

```
"keywords": "[u'Smartphone', u'Abmessung', u'Geh\xe4userand']"
```

so i want to utf8 decode the **Geh\xe4userand** string. i read in some post that i have to put it in "" and do the decoding but its not working. my code is

```
$tags = str_replace("'",'"',$tags);
$tags = preg_replace('/\[*\s*u(".*?")\]*/', "$1", $tags);
$tags = explode(',', $tags);
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        pr(utf8_encode($tag));
    }
    die;
```

the output i am getting is

```
<pre>"Smartphone"</pre><pre>"Abmessung"</pre><pre>"Geh\xe4userand"</pre>
```

i don't have access to the python code.

Comment: Fix the Python code instead; it is sending you a Python list literal with a Unicode escape, not UTF8. It should send you JSON instead, most likely. The `\xe4` character sequence encodes the codepoint U+00E4, but it is 4 literal ASCII characters.

Comment: If you cannot fix the Python code, you'll have to translate all `\xhh` 2-hex codes to map them to Latin-1 codepoints instead. Any `\uhhhh` 4-hex codes are Unicode code points, `\Uhhhhhhhh` 8-hex codepoints for Unicode codepoints outside the BMP, and then there are the `\n`, `\r` and `\t` escape codes for newline, carriage return and tab.

Comment: replaced the hex with appropriate character since changing python code can't happen soon.
thanx @Martijn Pieters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all feasible, fix the Python code instead; it is sending you a Python list literal with a Unicode escape, not UTF8. Ideally it should send you JSON instead.

The `\xe4` character sequence encodes the codepoint U+00E4, but it is using 4 literal ASCII characters (`\`, `x`, `e`, `4`).

Other Python literal rules:

- It'll use either single quotes or double quotes, depending on the contents, with a preference for single quotes. As a result you may have to handle escaped `\'` single quotes.
- Newlines, carriage returns and tabs are escaped to `\n`, `\r` and `\t` respectively.
- All other non-printable Latin-1 characters are escaped to `\xhh`, a two-digit hexadecimal encoding of the codepoint.
- If the literal starts with `u` it is a Unicode string, not a byte string, and any codepoint outside the Latin-1 subset but part of the Basic Multilingual Plane is escaped to `\uhhhh`, a four-digit hexadecimal encoding of the codepoint in the range U+0100 through to U+FFFF
- In a Unicode string you'll also find `\Uhhhhhhhh`, a eight-digit hexadecimal encoding non-BMP unicode codepoints in the range U+00010000 through to U+0001FFFF.